# Django-simple-friends friendship_accept

Tags: django, django-templates, django-urls

I'm working with Django-simple-friends and making progress but I'm stuck on "accepting" a request.

What keywords (if any) do I send in the url to accept the request. Do I send just the "from_user" and if so what does that look like in the url?

The url I currently have is:

```
{% url friendship_accept username={{from_user}} %}
```

The `{{from_user}}` is being passed in from the view.

The error I get is

> Could not parse the remainder: '{{from_user}}' from '{{from_user}}'

I greatly appreciate and feedback and expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing parametrs to template tag(which `{% url .. %}` is) you dont need to double `{{` them.

Take a look at [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url)  ad [source code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/base.py#L531) line 531

Feel free to dig framework from time to time it may help.

Comment: Awesome worked great. I started digging in more on the django doc (I've only been programming and working with django for about 4 months and am still getting familiar with the docs)